# Debug tools for node.js app in Bluemix don't seem to work

Tags: debugging, ibm-cloud

I have deployed a node.js app in Bluemix using `cf push`. I have removed the start: entry from manifest.yml. In Bluemix I have set the environment variable `BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE`to `devconsole+shell+inspector`. This restages the app.

But when I open the App Manager by adding `/bluemix-debug/manage/` I get a 404 error.

When I start Live Edit on the same project from DevOps Services I can open the App Manager. But I don't see what is different, it also seems to set the environment variable only.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you look at the application logs when your application is being restaged, both when manually setting the BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE flag and using DevOps Services, do you see any differences?

Comment: Why are you removing the start entry? Setting the env var doesn't restage the app, you need to issue a `cf restage <appname>`

Comment: `Why are you removing the start entry?` -- Because thats what the Bluemix doc says: `Most App Management utilities do not work if you set your start command in the manifest.yml file (command) or CF CLI (-c). Those methods are buildpack overrides, and are anti-patterns for starting Node.js applications. For best results, set the start command in the package.json file or Procfile.`

Comment: I have tried it again, once setting the environment variable with `cf set-env` and `cf restage` and monitoring the logs, then removing the environment variable again, restaging, then setting Live Edit to on in DevOps Services.

Both times I see that the app management utilities are installed when the droplet is built. But when the app is started after setting the environment manually, the app management utilities are never activated and started. They are when Live Edit is set to on in DevOps Services.

Comment: I followed some steps Harald mentioned and it did not work for me as well.

Comment: @RamVennam - Is that information in the docs incorrect or not applicable in this scenario? I am happy to open a work item for the doc team if something needs to be updated.

Comment: The docs information is correct.

Comment: @Sai: What do you mean with the documentation is correct?

I see at least one discrepancy in thze App Management section, How to configure App Management. It says to restart the app but I have learned that I need to restage the app. Which is the command given in the example. 

Under Restrictions it says that "Most App Management utilities do not work if you set your start command in the manifest.yml". Is this true or not?

Comment: Not a discrepancy -- you can restart the application to enable App Mgmt, but it forces the application to install all the dependencies at runtime, which can consume up to ~400MB of RAM in some cases.  If you do not have enough memory allocated, you will need to restage instead; there are logs from the buildpack during staging that should indicate this.

The manifest.yml restriction is also true; it would prevent the buildpack from starting the proxy agent and the additional app mgmt utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Live Edit tool will automatically add 256MB to your application to facilitate execution of the additional features, which is likely why it is working with Live Edit.

Manually enabling the feature, however, will not automatically bump up the memory.  Can you try adding some more memory to your application and restaging?

There are a couple of other limitations; refer to the Restrictions section on the [App Management docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/app_management.html).

EDIT: Found issue in comments below.  If `command: node app.js` is in manifest.yml, or if you are using `-c` with the CF CLI, it overrides the buildpack's ability to start the development utilities in App Mgmt.  This happens even if you have the start command correctly specified in `package.json` or `Procfile`.  To fix this, remove the manifest.yml entry, delete the application, and restage the application.

Comment: I am deploying a boilerplate app in a 512 MB instance. Should be more than enough to start the debugging tools, too. Have you tried starting debug mode from the command line lately? Does it work for you? If yes, what did you do to make it work?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed work... :) Which boilerplate application are you working with? The only thing I do is set `BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE` and restage the application.  It should be a single-instance application, start command only in package.json, and a restage to enable the features.  Although it shouldn't, the boilerplate may have an incorrectly set start command.  I'd like to address that ASAP.

I've just released a video that outlines how to use App Mgmt and a number of its utilities:
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/10/05/advanced-debugging-node-apps-bluemix/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Here is what I do: Boilerplate `Node.js Cloudant DB Web Starter`   

(1) Download the starter code to laptop and unzip it. 

(2) `cf set-env <app name> BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE devconsole+shell+inspector`

(3) Change in manifest.yml: memory: 512M -> 768M

(4) `cf push`

(5) <APP URL>/bluemix-debug/manage  => Cannot GET /bluemix-debug/manage

BUT: the logs show: Installing App Management. The following utilities are configured to be enabled and will be installed now: devconsole, shell, inspector

Comment: A ha! I found the issue... the starter code's `manifest.yml` has `command: node app.js`.  This overrides the buildpack's ability to start development utilities at runtime.  Please set it to `command: null` or delete that line entirely, delete your application, and repush.  (Note: You have to delete the app on Bluemix because `command` gets cached by the app, so removing that line in manifest.yml is not enough.)  It is unfortunate that our own boilerplates were following an anti-pattern, but I'll ensure it gets fixed!

Comment: Sai, that was it: delete the app (and only the app, not the services) from Bluemix, remove the `command:` statement from manifest.yml, push it once, set the environment, then restage the app. Voila, there  is a debugger. Thanks, you are my hero!